# Distribute token to multiple address

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm writing a smart contract to distribute the created tokens to multiple address. Looking around on the web I may found what I was looking for but I don't know how to insert the addresses in the field; I tried in different ways but none worked.
This is the function to distribute token:

```
function distributeToken(address[] addresses, uint256 _value) onlyOwner {
     for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
         balances[owner] -= _value;
         balances[addresses[i]] += _value;
         Transfer(owner, addresses[i], _value);
     }
}
```

and this is the function in the contract:

[image]

I tried to insert the addresses in these ways:

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003

['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001', '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002', '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003']

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003

but no one worked.
How can I solve this? Thank you

Comment: did it get execute for you? now, if enclosed with double-quote, the warning shows the transaction may fail & all gas will be consumed. And the transaction is passing with single-quote, and not quote, but unable to check the token transfer on the destination accounts.

Comment: Yes, I managed to execute it with double quote. Single quote pass the transaction but don't transfer tokens

Comment: You mean, the above function is added to your token contract itself, or in a separate contract?

Comment: The function is in the token contract

Comment: it could trigger the gas limitation problem when users try to send to too many addresses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The addresses should be in "s and not 's:

```
["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003"]
```

I tested this on [Remix](http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js) and it worked fine.